# Is there any cases where a 20 amps breaker would be OK for 14 AWG copper?

Tags: electrical, wiring, circuit-breaker

Is there any cases where a 20 amps breaker would be OK for 14 AWG copper cable ?

At first glance, this seems like a clear NO.

But I just went to replace a heater baseboard on a newly bought cabin. Found the cable to be 14 AWG copper at the baseboard entry. This baseboard is small, and nameplate says 2 amps. **I'm wondering if this has ever been to code** (even by a strech) ? Location is Canada, construction year is around 1980.

Maybe something like: Baseboard couldn't ever take more than 2 amps, and a short would trip the breaker anyway ? (But yeah, I guess code is not like that and has never been) I'm looking for a confirmation that this is and has always been a strict no.

The total circuit is three baseboards (2.09, 4.17 and 5.21 amps). So I assume the safest path is to downgrade the breaker, unless there's some extra load factor I need to add?

(this is on 240v but I assume it makes no difference)

Comment: Is the 14AWG wire permanently attached to the fixture (I.e. part of the fixture from the manufacturer)? If so, the code rules ignore this, just like a small wattage LED with built-in small wires. Despite this, any wires attached by the user (or an electrician) must comply with the rules for the breaker size.

Comment: I am like you in my knowledge, but guessing what happen in the past, was it kept tripping 15 amp breaker, so person changed to 20 amp.

Comment: @DoxyLover not sure what you mean. The 14 AWG goes from the wall right into the fixture and connects internally to the heating element connector with wire nuts. I guess that's as permanent as it gets :-)

Comment: Load factor is 125% for continuous loads, I think it's the same in Canada. So it should be fine on  15A breaker.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are certain cases (see [recommended wire gauge for well pump and float switch](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/225273/recommended-wire-gauge-for-well-pump-and-float-switch) for one) involving certain motor loads which can be on a larger breaker than the wire size needed. But that doesn't apply to *most* residential situations, such as heaters.

However, there is a big difference between the wiring that is *part of an appliance* and the wiring between the breaker and the appliance. From your description, it sounds like this may be the wiring in your heater. That is determined by UL (or other certifying agency) and not directly by the electrical code. There are different rules, for a bunch of reasons. This is quite common, and actually makes a lot of sense since the heater only draws a couple of Amps. The wiring from the breaker to the heater needs to match the breaker size, because (among other reasons) somebody could decide to replace the little heater with a much bigger one that draws 16 Amps, which would then be too much for 14 AWG wire. (And that heater would likely have internal wiring larger than 14 AWG for the same reason.)

So the thing to check is the wire in the wall. Easiest is usually at the breaker. If it is NM cable (aka Romex) then it should be labeled on the cable sheath. If it is individual wires then it should be labeled on each wire. For 20 Amp, it should be at least 12 AWG.

The total load is < 12 Amps, so a 15 Amp breaker, if it turns out the relevant wiring is too small for a 20 Amp circuit, is OK. Keep in mind though that continuous loads such as heaters (think: all off and came in to the cabin in the winter - could take hours to heat up) are derated, so max. 12 Amps continuous of a 15 Amp circuit and max. 16 Amps continuos on a 20 Amp circuit. If you have 12 AWG wire, leave that breaker at 20 Amp, as it gives you enough room to add another heater (up to 4 Amps) if you want to. If you downbreaker to 15 Amp then you are basically maxed out.

Comment: Thanks, that confirms it. The romex is 14 (at least in the last leg from second to last heater, so it will be a new breaker)

Comment: If the first leg (breaker to first heater) is 12 AWG then you may have a situation where the first heater was put in according to code (12 AWG, 20 Amp breaker) and then later someone else added another heater but used 14 AWG when they should not have done so (because of the breaker, not because of the heater). Change to 15A and you should be fine.

Answer (score 1):

People upsize breakers for lots of reasons - they're getting nuisance trips (because they're overloading the circuit), or they happen to have the wrong size breaker on hand and don't want to go to the store.

> Maybe something like: Baseboard couldn't ever take more than 2 amps, and a short would trip the breaker anyway ? (But yeah, I guess code is not like that and has never been) I'm looking for a confirmation that this is and has always been a strict no.

It's *safety* that isn't that simple.  Code isn't written to inconvenience you.

> The total circuit is three baseboards (2.09, 4.17 and 5.21 amps). So I assume the safest path is to downgrade the breaker, unless there's some extra load factor I need to add?

Your total there is 11.47 amps.

When you apply a 125% derate (because they are heater) you get 14.34 amps.

**Apply a 15A breaker**. What's the problem with that? They're ten bucks.

---

---

The "15A on #14" is fairly ironclad, and is defined in NEC 240.4(D).  However, for *certain specific* loads, you can look at 240.4(G). Sometimes, if you go far enough down that rabbit hole, you will find an exception allowing a larger breaker. Generally in residential that only happens on large motors, e.g. air conditioning units and well pumps.

*It certainly will never happen on a heater or heating load. In fact, those have the 125% derate applied to them, so 12.1A of heater isn't even allowed a 15A breaker!*

There is one last exception, at 110.3(B): you must follow labeling and instructions.  If the UL White Book says equipment can be approved with particular wire and breaker sizes, and an NRTL has inspected and approved the labeling and instructions that say that, then you can (must, really) follow them.

Comment: > Apply a 15A breaker. What's the problem with that? They're ten bucks. 
Yes, totally agree. The question was trying to understand how this situation came to be, and whether it was code at any point. On changing the breaker, that's probably a different question, but it happens to be a delisted Commander panel. I never changed a breaker, so I guess I'll have learning to do.

Comment: Oh dear yes, unobtanium breakers are another reason.  But Commander?  Or Challenger (easy)?  Post some photos of the panel and any labeling.